# How can I remove the name field from a json array?

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have a json array like this:

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {Id: 1, Name: "bask"}
1: {Id: 2, Name: "voll"}
2: {Id: 3, Name: "badminton"}
```

I want to turn it into something like this:

```
{1:"bask",2:"voll",3:"badminton"}
```

Comment: I suggest using `reduce()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to loop through array and build a object of desired `key/value` pair

```js
let data = [{Id: 1, Name: "bask"},{Id: 2, Name: "voll"},{Id: 3, Name: "badminton"}]

let output = data.reduce((op, {Id, Name}) => {
  op[Id] = Name
  return op
},{})

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) with the maped key/value pairs.

```js
var array = [{ Id: 1, Name: "bask" }, { Id: 2, Name: "voll" }, { Id: 3, Name: "badminton" }],
    object = Object.fromEntries(array.map(({ Id, Name }) => [Id, Name]));

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the `reduce()` function!

```
let array = [
    {Id: 1, Name: "bask"},
    {Id: 2, Name: "voll"},
    {Id: 3, Name: "badminton"} 
];
console.log(_.reduce(array, function(result, obj){
    result[obj.Id] = obj.Name;
  return result;
}, {}));
```

You can checkout [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.14#reduce) an awesome library with many other such utilities!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `reduce()`:

```
var a = [
  {Id: 1, Name: "bask"},
  {Id: 2, Name: "voll"},
  {Id: 3, Name: "badminton"}
]

b = a.reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc[item.Id] = item.Name;
  return acc;
}
console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in different ways, here one of them.

```
let dataArray = [
  {id: 1, name: 'bask'},
  {id: 2, name: 'voll'},
  {id: 3, name: 'badminton'}
]

let ouputObject = {}

dataArray.map(data => {
  ouputObject[`${data.id}`] = data.name
})

console.log(ouputObject)
```

outputObject will be

```
Object {
  1: "bask",
  2: "voll",
  3: "badminton"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) :

```js
var arr = [{
 Id: 1,
 Name: "bask"
}, {
 Id: 2,
 Name: "voll"
}, {
 Id: 3,
 Name: "badminton"
}];

var reduceObj = arr.reduce(function(result, currentElement) {
   result[currentElement.Id] = currentElement.Name;
   return result;
}, {});

console.log(reduceObj);
```

Using [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) :

```js
var arr = [{
 Id: 1,
 Name: "bask"
}, {
 Id: 2,
 Name: "voll"
}, {
 Id: 3,
 Name: "badminton"
}];

var mapObject = {}

arr.map(obj => {
  mapObject[obj.Id] = obj.Name
})

console.log(mapObject);
```